# Limit the Number of Requests in Web Server

Tags: web-applications

I am working in a web application where I am using the Tomcat as a web server. My requirement is to allow the maximum 100 requests at a time can be processd by my web application. And whenever application gets the 100+ request, application should put that in request on hold.

How can I limit the number of requests in a web application?

Answer (score 0):

you should have a look in the settings file (should be /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf under Linux). Search for MaxClients option. For example, I use a small apache server at home which can process 300 simultaneous requests (connections).

or see this http://docs.racket-lang.org/web-server-internal/limit.html